# How to get youtube autoplay only once in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube, web

I just ad youtube video URL to one of my [freelance wordpress website](http://freelancefront.com) but the youtube video continue autoplay while I want it to play just once. Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to provide more information? Add any code you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

I found a gem of snippet for your problem.Try the link below.Hope it helps....
http://erichickstech.com/how-to-autoplay-play-a-youtube-video-only-once-by-setting-a-cookie/

Try this plugin if you do not want to mess up with cookies and javascript...
https://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-embed-plus/
Hope this answer helps...

Comment: Mandy8055 thank you for replying on my question. However none of these answers are the solution i'm looking for. I elaborate more.

Comment: I am using colormag wp theme. There is an option "Header Media" where you can use "11 characters code" of a youtube video. so when I used a video here its running well but doesn't stop and autoplay again n again. I want it to autoplay just once on everytime the page is refreshed or visited first time.